# String wont convert to given value - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm confused as to why my first column wont transfer to a string. When I print my df after performing the conversion, its still displaying the column with the string characters M or B, instead of 1 or 0.

```
header_list = ["Diagnosis", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" ,"16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
                   "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]
    df = pd.read_csv(('data1.csv'), names = header_list)
    df.set_index('Diagnosis')
    df.Diagnosis.replace(to_replace=['B', 'M'], value=[0, 1])
    print(df)
```

output

```
  Diagnosis      1      2       3  ...      27      28      29       30
0           M  17.99  10.38  122.80  ...  0.7119  0.2654  0.4601  0.11890
1           M  20.57  17.77  132.90  ...  0.2416  0.1860  0.2750  0.08902
2           M  19.69  21.25  130.00  ...  0.4504  0.2430  0.3613  0.08758
3           M  11.42  20.38   77.58  ...  0.6869  0.2575  0.6638  0.17300
4           M  20.29  14.34  135.10  ...  0.4000  0.1625  0.2364  0.07678
..        ...    ...    ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
564         M  21.56  22.39  142.00  ...  0.4107  0.2216  0.2060  0.07115
565         M  20.13  28.25  131.20  ...  0.3215  0.1628  0.2572  0.06637
566         M  16.60  28.08  108.30  ...  0.3403  0.1418  0.2218  0.07820
567         M  20.60  29.33  140.10  ...  0.9387  0.2650  0.4087  0.12400
568         B   7.76  24.54   47.92  ...  0.0000  0.0000  0.2871  0.07039
```

Comment: it needs to be assigned back: `df['Diagnosis'] = df.Diagnosis.replace(to_replace=['B', 'M'], value=[0, 1])`

Comment: also `map` is more intuitive here IMO: `df['Diagnosis'] = df.Diagnosis.map({'B': 0, 'M': 1})`

Comment: `set_index` also needs to be assigned back: `df = df.set_index('Diagnosis')`